# Bijective bounded linear operator is invertible

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

The following is an exercise from Halmos book "A Hilbert space problem book" :

**Exercise:** If $H$ and $K$ are Hilbert spaces, and if $A$ is a bounded linear transformation that maps $H$ one to one and onto $K$, then $A$ is invertible.

He gives the following solution for this:

[image] [image]

I do not know why he consider the operator $0$ in the role of $A^*$. Clearly $0$ is not bijective, so why does he state this part? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this is a special case of the (more difficult and important) [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28functional_analysis%29).

Answer (score 1):

For operator $A^*=0$ the condition $\Vert A^*g\Vert=1$ is always false. By the fundamental rules of logic False implies anything and in particular that $\Vert g\Vert\leq 1/\delta$.

One could say for example that $\Vert A^*g\Vert=1\implies\pi=10^5$ and would be absolutely correct.

Comment: Operator $0$ is not satisfy in the assumption, so I can not understand why does he state this part in his proof?

Comment: This is not a step of the proof, this is an explanation why one had to keep in mind that $\ker A^*\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much